# Chance of drawing a number from [0,1], of which the decimal expansion contains no 4s or 5s?

Tags: probability-theory

If we have a uniform probability distribution on the real interval $[0, 1]$, and $A := \{r \in [0, 1] \mid \text{the decimal expansion of } r \text{ has no 4s or 5s}\}$, what is $P(A)$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not sure how to clarify further, but to give an example, $0.1236 \in V$, but $0.1234 \not \in V$. What is the probability that if we draw a random number $r \in [0, 1]$ (uniformly), that we also have $r \in V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A_{n}$ is the event that the first $n$ digits are not $4$ and $5$, then $\forall n=1,2,...$ we have

$$P(A)\leq P(A_{n})=\left(\frac{8}{10}\right)^{n}$$

Thus $P(A)=0$

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this to me!